# Android ARM64 kernel disassembly IDA pro64

Tags: arm, android

I extracted Samsung Galaxy S6 kernel image from its stock boot.img. The result is a raw code kernel image. I load into IDA 6.8 (64-bit) using `ROM Start: 0xffffffc000205000 size:0x18C020000, load address:0xffffffc000205000 size:0x18C020000` which is the address of `_text/_stext` inside it's kallsyms, it does not disassemble correctly and recognise nearly everything as data. On the other hand, using the _text/stext function for a 32-bit ARM Note 4 kernel image at `0xC0008000` works perfectly. Does any one have any idea how to disassemble ARM64 android image correctly? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the segment bitness to 64-bit. It then disassembled correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi, @perror, he answered me on IDA forums :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a mix of 64 and 32 bit code, to disassemble the 32bit segments, change the segment bitness to 32  ( via Alt-S )

then you can disassemble those sections as either arm32, or thumb code.

A problem will arise when you want to be able to decompile both the 32 and 64 bit code.
IDA will only be able to decompile the 64 bit code.